# Gtk loop or Cron for timer

Tags: python

Well, I have created a python script, which checks the number of uncompleted tasks of tasque and displays it using pynotify periodically. My question is how do I implement this timer. I can think of two things. A Cron job to execute a python script periodically or using a python script which uses a gtk loop to call the specified function for checking periodically.

Comment: The cron job sounds better, since the gtk loop would require Python to be running all the time.

Comment: +1 to the cron job, for the same reason Rafe Kettler gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron job. It's more likely to be "in line" with actual time, since it's a more stable and time-tested choice. It's also less demanding on resources than using a loop in Python since it doesn't require a constant Python interpreter process, and is probably better optimized than pyGTK (choice is mature, stable software vs. less mature, less stable).